# Mapping Reduction from INFINITE to REG

Tags: turing-machines, rice-theorem

given the following languages:

- $INFINITE_{T M}=\{\langle M\rangle: M$ is a TM with $|L(M)|=\infty\}$.
- $R E G_{T M}=\{\langle M\rangle: M$ is a TM with $L(M) \in \mathrm{REG}\}$.

prove the following reduction:

$I N F I N I T E_{T M} \leq_m R E G_{T M}$
I'm having difficulties, building the $M_f$ machine

would love for some help, got no clue for now :)

edit:
if that wasn't clear, would love for initial direction, not for formal solution

Comment: We're not looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task and a request for us to solve it for you.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  Can you ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the same problem you happen to be working on.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to define REG.

Comment: I don't get why you should be so toxic, and adding -1 to the post, I'm not here for you to solve my exercises, I'm here to learn, and when I state i don't have any clue, I mean it, I've tried to solve this questions for like couple of days, and still don't have any clue how to begin, yes I know what is reduction and I know that it's needs to get machines that in one language and output machine that from the other language, 
would love for some help, thank you

Comment: ah and another thing , this attitude is the reason I considering not to continue taking part in this community, I know there are many that will continue participate here, but if you are looking to expand the community find a better way to answer frustrated students , who has no clue how to proceed in this question, and no , I didn't ask for a formal answer, a beginning of direction to solution would be nice

Comment: E.g. let $M_f$ accept any non-regular language like $\{a^{p_n}| n \in \mathbb N\}$ $p_n$ primes, and only fill in all the remaining $a^i$ if $M$ accepts infinitely many words. Note that checking if a word exists such that a TM accepts a word longer than $i$ is in RE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reduction mapping should work.
For any input $M\in TM$ we define $M_f$ as follows:
For any $x\in\Sigma^*$,

1. If $x=0^n1^n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ then $M_f$ Accepts.
2. Else, we run simultaneously $M$ on all words $y\in\Sigma^*$ in Minlex order such that $|y|\geq|x|$. If $M$ Accepts, then $M_f$ Accepts.
3. If no word was Accepted, we continue running.

It isn't difficult to see that $M_f$ is computable, and now I will leave you to prove that it is indeed a correct reduction.

Comment: Yup done something like this , a couple of days ago :)
thank you very much! you are the best